# data returns undefined in datatables ajax loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Good day to the masters here at stack!
I was having this problem about getting the data of every cells in a row using datatable.
data table was loaded through ajax and I want to convert every cell into an input box when I click on edit action. I was able to do the but one is that the input boxes got a value of undefined.

Any one can please explain what's going on with this?

```
rowEdit: function( $row ) {
        var _self = this,
            data;

        data = this.datatable.row( $row.get(0) ).data();
        console.log(data);
        $row.children( 'td' ).each(function(index) {
            var $this = $( this );

            if ( $this.hasClass('actions') ) {
                _self.rowSetActionsEditing( $row );
            } else {
                if (index <= 3) {
                    $this.html( '<input type="text" class="form-control input-block" value="' + data[index] + '"/>' );

                    console.log(data[index]);
                } else {
                    $this.html('<a href="#" class="on-editing save-row"><i class="fa fa-save"></i></a>'
                        + '&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" class="on-editing cancel-row"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>'
                        + '<a href="#" class="hidden on-default edit-row"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>'
                        + '&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" class="hidden on-default remove-row"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>');
                }
            }
        });
    },
```

that is the code that I use to get the cell values. notice the `console.log(data)`? I put that there to see what actually data contains and what I got is this

```
Object {DT_RowId: "row_913", name: "Aaron Stracke I", address: "2854 Selina Forges Apt. 667↵New Amy, TN 33666", phone: "877-931-7788", email: "n/a"}
```

ont my code I tried looping through each cells to get the values from data but was unable to. so next is to check what values will I get with the data plus index `console.log(data[index]);` and returned undefined

[table before clicking edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Br23W.png)

[after clicking on pencil icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBs8M.png)

thank you so much guys and any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Mention the specific library version and reference url for libarary. so that one can suggest the API

Comment: Thank you for mentioning that.
I'm using version 1.10.7 https://datatables.net/reference/index

Comment: is `rowEdit` inbuilt functionality of DataTables? . Are you using datatable editor or you've just used any other implementations?

Comment: No. It's a function that I've created to be called by this code
`this.$table
     .on('click', 'a.save-row', function( e ) {
         e.preventDefault();
          
  _self.rowSave( $(this).closest( 'tr' ) );
   })
 .on('click', 'a.cancel-row', function( e ) {
 e.preventDefault();

   _self.rowCancel( $(this).closest( 'tr' ) );
    })
 .on('click', 'a.edit-row', function( e ) {
        e.preventDefault();

        _self.rowEdit( $(this).closest( 'tr' ) );
    })`

Comment: I tried using the code format but its not working

Comment: Nope it wont format in comments.  I've implemented the same in a different manner using [jEditable](http://legacy.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/editable.html) plugin.

Comment: Let me take a look

Comment: s there a way that I could loop through the object array and get their value on each inputboxes in a table row?

or am i getting the td values wrong?

Comment: See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42190867/3543808)

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the var `index` can have values like 0, 1, 2, 3 (index <= 3) and you are assigning value to the input elements as `data[index]`

So data[0], data[1], data[2] or data[3] should be exist. According to your console output, data object has no such member.

Comment: Yes that's right, rather than data[0] or data[index] which has undefined out put on console I tried console.log(data.name); and it returned the correct data that I wanted. but still I can't do something like this because I want my code to get the cell values and put then in a row with input boxes for editing.

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented the in-place editing in Datatables using [jEditable](https://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable) plugin with few modifications. I would highly recommend the plugin and it has quite good documentation.

In your case `data` is returning an object.

```
Object {DT_RowId: "row_913", name: "Aaron Stracke I", address: "2854 Selina Forges Apt. 667↵New Amy, TN 33666", phone: "877-931-7788", email: "n/a"}
```

Ideally it should return an array as shown below

```
["row_913", "Aaron Stracke I", "2854 Selina Forges Apt. 667↵New Amy, TN 33666", "877-931-7788", "n/a"]
```

see the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gangadharjannu/b382c9z4/)

```
rowEdit: function( $row ) {
        var _self = this,
            data;

        data = this.datatable.row(_self).data();
        $(_self).children('td').each(function(index) {
            var $this = $(this);

            if ( $this.hasClass('actions') ) {
                _self.rowSetActionsEditing( $row );
            } else {
                if (index <= 3) {
                    $this.html( '<input type="text" class="form-control input-block" value="' + data[index] + '"/>' );

                    console.log(data[index]);
                } else {
                    $this.html('<a href="#" class="on-editing save-row"><i class="fa fa-save"></i></a>'
                        + '&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" class="on-editing cancel-row"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>'
                        + '<a href="#" class="hidden on-default edit-row"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>'
                        + '&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" class="hidden on-default remove-row"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>');
                }
            }
        });
    },
```

Comment: Ok I'll try this now and see how it'll go.

Comment: I assume you wanted to iterate over `td` in `row`. If that is what you want above code will surely works

Comment: Same thing happened. my first code was also able to get the row instance and so does your code but my real problem is how could i get to loop though every cell in that row and assigned a value to those inputs.

on my code I tried using `data[index]` or `data[0] data[1] ...` but those returned undefined. undefined because I was fetching the values by indexes and not by keys.
data returns
`Object {DT_RowId: "row_913", name: "Aaron Stracke I", address: "2854 Selina Forges Apt. 667↵New Amy, TN 33666", phone: "877-931-7788", email: "n/a"}`
so to get a value i must use `data.name`

Comment: is there a way to convert data content from
`Object {DT_RowId: "row_913", name: "Aaron Stracke I", address: "2854 Selina Forges Apt. 667↵New Amy, TN 33666", phone: "877-931-7788", email: "n/a"}`
to
`Object {"row_913", "Aaron Stracke I", "2854 Selina Forges Apt. 667↵New Amy, TN 33666", "877-931-7788", "n/a"}`
since this format will be using indexes that would go with the .each loop?

Comment: 'Object {DT_RowId: "row_913", name: "Aaron Stracke I", address: "2854 Selina Forges Apt. 667↵New Amy, TN 33666", phone: "877-931-7788", email: "n/a"}' to Array ["row_913", "Aaron Stracke I", "2854 Selina Forges Apt. 667↵New Amy, TN 33666", "877-931-7788", "n/a"]?

Comment: because you can't use indexes in Object but you could in Array

Comment: then is there a way to convert that object into an array that I can use?

Comment: var tempArr=[];
for(var key in data){
    if(data.hasOwnProperty(key)){
     b.push(data[key]);
    }
}

Comment: I've achieved the same result using this shorter code
`var arr = Object.keys(data).map(function (key) { return data[key]; });`